# When is an erratum necessary?

Tags: soft-question, journals

A typo, a spelling error etc., in a published article, is definitely not enough for issuing an erratum.

If a mistake destroys a main result, then an erratum is definitely necessary, and the proof should be rewritten, if it's possible to fix.

What about cases in between?  What if a small lemma, remark is not correctly stated?  What about a mistake in the proof that is actually very easy to fix? What about a wrong number in the calculation? What if ... (you name the case) ...?

Comment: Should this be moved to academia.stackexchange.com or is it to be expected that answers will be specific for mathematics?

Comment: @Dirk more specific for mathematics, in the sense that I'm not talking about data, experiment and so on, I'm talking about proofs and statements.

Comment: Mathematicians are generally very shy at admitting mistakes and publishing errata. I also think that there is a very big difference between the publishing culture of mathematicians and the publishing culture in other scientific disciplines. So migrating this question to academia.stackexchange.com is probably not such a great idea.

Comment: @AndréHenriques I would like to hear some stories about shy mathematicians. :) Is that also a bad idea to point out the mistakes of others?

Comment: @AndréHenriques I thought the same and just wanted to hear the OPs and other opinions.

Comment: For mistakes with no effect on the main result I would just fix the arxiv/homepage version and not bother with the published version. If your local mistake affects work of others, you should inform the interested parties. If there are many of them, consider a full blown erraturm.

Comment: Jordan Ellenberg wrote a fascinating blog post about an error that was found in one of his preprints: https://quomodocumque.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/homological-stability-for-hurwitz-spaces-ii-temporarily-withdrawn/ He was rightly commended by many of his readers for the way he dealt with this error. The post, and the comments that follow, is well worth a read.

Comment: Although this question sounds like correcting ones own published error, the  MathOverflow question in the Related list "How do I fix someone's published error?" addresses the case that the author does not publish an erratum.  Reviewing that question may inspire answers to this one.  Gerhard "Still Don't Need Stinking Badges" Paseman, 2015.11.20

Comment: @AndréHenriques  [academia.se] has a tag [mathematics](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics)  "On standards or conventions specific to mathematics as an academic discipline, and programs that lead to a degree in this field." with more than 500 questions. So it is not quite clear to me why it would be "not such a great idea" to migrate it there. Anyway it is too late now. But for future occasions it could be relevant.

Comment: If the mistake is serious you publish a correction, if it is not, you don't. You wrote this yourself. What other answer you are trying to obtain? How to decide what is serious and what is not? Who can decide this except yourself?

Comment: Errata can be your friends. Your erratum results in a reference to your original paper. If your erratum contains an error, publish an erratum to the erratum, which references both the erratum and the original paper.  The number of references to your publications grows as an O(N^2) process, where N is the number of errata.

Answer (score 17):

The evidence on arXiv does not seem to support the assertion that mathematicians are significantly more reluctant to issue an erratum than, say, physicists:

- [errata
  in mathematics](http://arxiv.org/find/grp_math/1/OR+ti:+erratum+abs:+erratum/0/1/0/all/0/1) (92 items)
- [errata
  in physics](http://arxiv.org/find/grp_physics/1/OR+ti:+erratum+abs:+erratum/0/1/0/all/0/1) (160 items)

The factor of two in the number of errata between physics and mathematics correlates well with the total number of arXiv submissions (about three times as many in physics than in mathematics). Incidentally, only a very small percentage of arXiv submissions are errata (the total number math articles is about 150,000).

I do notice that many of the mathematics errata are limited to the arXiv version, and not incorporated in the journal. The idea being, I would think, that issuing an erratum for a relatively minor issue is a service to the reader, who will likely consult the arXiv version and will therefore be alerted to the error. This would obviously be unacceptable for an error that invalidates the entire work, but those happen more rarely.

In this connection I find it interesting to note that mathematicians *withdraw* more papers from the arXiv than physicists, 128 versus 90 in the last year. I presume this says something about the different consequences of a small mistake in the two disciplines.

Comment: +1 for arXiv. Do not forget to point out that the arXiv version is corrected in the comment field, or else many readers will think that the published version  is the more up to date.

Comment: There was an article in the *Notices* a couple of years ago on this topic. http://www.ams.org/notices/201304/rnoti-p418.pdf Among other things, the article said, "There  is  no  reason  to  think engineers and mathematicians make mistakes less often than other researchers, while there is some evidence that the research cultures of these fields discourage publishing corrections." Neal Koblitz, however, has a different opinion. http://www.ams.org/notices/201307/rnoti-p839.pdf

Comment: In order to compare two fields (such as math and physics), instead of absolute numbers, it might be a better idea to give the *percentage* of arxiv submissions which are errata.

Comment: @AndréHenriques --- good point, I added this info

Comment: "Errata in Mathematics" – sounds like a good title for a new journal....

Answer (score 15):

I can't speak for everyone, but since you ask for examples, I've published "errata" at least a couple of times. Once was a paper (in *Inventionnes*, quite embarrassing) where the statement of the main theorem was false due to a mistake in the proof! Luckily, a small modification of the proof gave a weaker, but still interesting, true result. This comes under your heading of "If a mistake destroys a main result,..." The other situation, which you didn't mention, was a case where one of the main results of a paper was an immediate consequence of an earlier paper that we had not known about. After our paper was in press, someone pointed this out, so we submitted an "addendum".

Answer (score 15):

It happened to me, too. On my thesis. Published in *Annals of Math.* I got a note from A. Fröhlich saying that in a seminar in London, they hadn’t been able to verify an involved inequality-computation in a proof. Indeed, my computation was completely wrong. Fortunately, the lemma wasn’t essential to the whole except for producing useful counterexamples. What was most embarrassing was that if I had tried to pull the wool over the reader’s eyes, I couldn’t have chosen a better method of deception. I sent in a one-page correction with a replacement-statement that was rather weaker, but still good for the counterexamples. A few years later, I found a correct proof of the original statement.

Answer (score 10):

Checking MathSciNet in the five-year period from 2010 to 2014, there were 1319 entries with "erratum" or "errata" in the title.  Sampling a few dozen of them, most cases involve a misstatement severe enough to affect the statement of a theorem.  In a few cases, something was inadvertently left out, such as MATLAB code or an author's name. For perspective, during this period, there were 525795 items added to MathSciNet.